# consultas join en postgresql para seleccionar datos específicos de dos o mas tablas

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Que tal como están me cruce con un inconveniente y la verdad no se si es posible busque en documentación talvez alguien algunas ves lo intento, el asunto va así quiero hacer una consulta join para dos tablas en las cuales seleccionar filas especificas ya que las dos tablas son iguales y luego que de las dos me saque datos desde de las mismas fechas ahora subo mis consultas:

```
SELECT 
    A.name, 
    A.fecha_dia, 
    A.point_x, 
    A.point_y, 
    A.precio_m2, 
    A.superficie, 
    A.no, 
    A.condominio, 
    A.no_cons, 
    B.name, 
    B.fecha_dia, 
    B.point_x, 
    B.point_y, 
    B.precio_m2, 
    B.superficie, 
    B.no, 
    B.condominio, 
    B.no_cons 
FROM comparables_2016 A 
JOIN comparables_scz_2016 B ON A.gid = B.gid;
```

Así selecciono de las dos tablas los datos que necesito pero lo que quiero es seleccionar aparte de dos tablas por fechas definidas ejemplo: que selecciones datos de hace 6 meses para adelante, intente hacerlo de esta manera pero no da:

```
SELECT 
    A.name, 
    A.fecha_dia, 
    A.point_x, 
    A.point_y, 
    A.precio_m2, 
    A.superficie, 
    A.no, 
    A.condominio, 
    A.no_cons, 
    B.name, 
    B.fecha_dia, 
    B.point_x, 
    B.point_y, 
    B.precio_m2, 
    B.superficie, 
    B.no, 
    B.condominio, 
    B.no_cons 
FROM comparables_2016 A 
JOIN comparables_scz_2016 B ON A.gid = B.gid
WHERE B.fecha_dia >= '2021-01-01' and A.fecha_dia >= '2021-01-01';
```

Intentando de esta manera no me selecciona nada talvez estoy en algún error por que a lo que quiero llegar es a poder hacer join con 3 o 4 tablas todas ellas son iguales tienen los mismos espacios.
Si alguien alguna ves logro hacerlo vendría bien una guía se lo agradecería mucho. gracias

Comment: Ponle un `LEFT JOIN` en vez de `JOIN` y revisa los resultados. Otra prueba sería verificar si: `SELECT * FROM comparables_2016 
WHERE fecha_dia >= '2021-01-01' and fecha_dia >= '2021-01-01'` y `SELECT * FROM comparables_scz_2016 
WHERE fecha_dia >= '2021-01-01' and fecha_dia >= '2021-01-01'` Arrojan los mismos datos. Otra cosa que nos debes decir es de qué tipo es `fecha_dia` en ambas tablas.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda efectivamente si las dos tablas son iguales tienes los mismos espacios, son de diferentes dptos entran los mismos registros lo quiero es generar una consulta que me muestre los registros de hace 6 meses para adelante, el tipo de fecha_dia es tipo date. gracias

Comment: ¿Probaste con LEFT JOIN? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que muestran las consultas ejecutadas por separado?

Comment: ¿Probaste con `B.fecha_dia >= '2021-01-01' or A.fecha_dia >= '2021-01-01' `?